# Headless Google Chrome - Change Timezone

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

Is it possible to launch a headless Google Chrome and programatically set a timezone for testing? It doesn't seem to be present as a [shell switch](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc).

I'd like to be able to run tests with varying timezones to confirm that the front end is handling timezone conversion properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently came across [this script](https://gist.github.com/prasadsilva/225fd0394a51e52bf62f) that solves this issue. It supports a few configuration options. From the code:

```
# Change this to the spoof a different timezone. Helpful for testing timezone specific client facing content.
export TZ="America/Los_Angeles"

# Permanent directory to store the user-data directory of your 'fresh'
# Chrome configuration.
fresh_dir="$HOME/.fresh-chrome"

# Temporary directory in which to create new user-data directories for
# temporary Chrome instances.
tmp_dir="/tmp"
```

Interestingly, the `TZ` variable is not part of the script. Perhaps Chrome reads the `TZ` environment variable when it starts? I'm not sure, but this works for now.

Comment: Jamie, how did you launch it headless?

Adding --headless to the start script does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Actually I think its  exec open -na "Google Chrome" --args "--user-data-dir=$user_dir" "--headless"

Comment: @Cameron yeah if you have Chrome already open already you need `-n`

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Windows?