# Set Time Zone in Headless Chrome in Windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

Referencing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463925/headless-google-chrome-change-timezone), I'm looking for something similar but for Windows... My server is in UTC, but the end users are in a different timezone... I'm using headless Chrome to print to PDF but I need to set the timezone info so that the printed times are correct.

Your help is greatly appreciated.